# Are environment variables (created using process.env) shared between parent & child node processes?

Tags: node.js

I'm wondering why the environment variables created using `process.env.SOME_VARIABLE` in main node process are available in any child processes created using Node's `Fork` API?

To give you an example, I am building a desktop application using Electron. In that application, I am setting an envrionment variable for proxy settings through the UI using code something like the following:

```
process.env.HTTPS_PROXY = 'proxy server url';
```

Now from this application I need to run some tasks in the background and for that I am launching new processes using Node's `Fork` API. What I noticed is that when I print the value of this variable in the child process, I am getting the value I set in the UI (parent process).

It is my understanding that when I spawn a child process using `Fork`, a new process is created which is completely independent of the parent process (except for the IPC channel created between them). If these processes are independent of each other, then how come these environment variables that I define in the parent process are available in the child process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are partially correct. Whenever the `fork()` process is called, the new child process is independent, as you rightly said apart from the IPC. But the key here is that this child inherits its "environment" from its parent. So essentially, any 'environment' variable in parent would be a part of child but any 'shell' variable will not be. Similar concept applies for 'exported' variables also.

Comment: Thanks Anshul. Is there some documentation link you can point to where I can read more about this?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/130985/if-processes-inherit-the-parents-environment-why-do-we-need-export?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) would help :)

Comment: Thanks! The link you shared was indeed helpful.